# Plotting the parameters of Mathieu equation for stability region

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, special-functions

I am trying to plot stability regions of Mathieu equation with a and q parameters, I plot this and now i want that i fix the value of x between -5 and 5, and corresponding to each value of x,I get values of a and q and then plot a vs q, can i do that in Mathematica?[image: image of code and the plot of x vs t]

Comment: There are a number of questions already on plotting the stability regions of Mathieu functions like this one: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189529/plot-a-mathieu-stability-chart?r=SearchResults Have you had a chance to check out the answers to some of these questions to see if they do what you want?

Comment: Could you include your code as text instead of an image?  Also what do you mean by "fix the value of x between -5 and 5, and corresponding to each value of x,I get values of a and q"?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, Kamal! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign!

Comment: here is the code...
xsol = ParametricNDSolve[{x''[t] + (a - 2*q*Cos[2*t])*x[t] == 0, 
   x'[0] == 1, x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 10}, {a, q}],       Table[x[a, q][t] /. xsol, {a, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 5}],

Comment: fixing value of x means some curves go beyond 5 in x axis and some below 5, so I want to get those value of a and q for which value of x lies between 5 and -5.

Comment: You can add your code to the post by clicking the "edit" button below your post. You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful